# Proper UX/UI design for image upload and form on android

Tags: forms, android, uploading

I am looking for an advice how to properly design a layout for an android activity that should handle the following:

1. car image uploaded from android gallery (up to 8 images).
2. fill in some details on the car such as make,model,fuel etc and eventually some free text.
3. submit the form.

One of my thoughts were to let the user choose images and based on the amount of images they will be filled in a grid view, once finished the page will automatically be scrolled down to the form section where he should fill in all details. However as my experience as a designer is not so great I would like to hear for any advice from an experienced UX/UI designer.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest a wizard like flow:

- Select Images (viewpager style) via an image picker
- have mandatory and optional inputs
- have a system summary before uploading

Comment: The reason that I am not using view pager is since it doesnt has a RTL support. so implementing view pager with LTR layout in RTL application can impact the user experience, do you have any other ideas I can use to achieve this? how can i use the scroll view to page between different layouts?

Comment: Viewpager is just one of examples. My point is the wizard style to make them simple. For the layout of images, scroll view for images with bottom bar is another option like your statement.